# ¿Como guardar un conjunto de datos que vienen de un ciclo while?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

hola necesito sugerencias estoy muy perdido en este tema, tengo una tabla html la cual la creo mediante una consulta select desde la BD el detalle es que mis resultados los muestro conforme a un ciclo while , y después esos resultados los quiero guardar en otra tabla de la base de datos pero no se como hacerlo ya que en una sola variable vienen todos mis registros incluidos del ciclo while.

Esta es mi tabla html donde dice partes y accesorios, van varios registros pero en mi consulta todo esta la en variable $row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9S6K.png) que esta dentro de un input entonces a la hora de guardar los datos nuevamente en otra tabla de la BD no se inserta nada.

lo mismo ocurre con mi input donde quiero insertar la cantidad lo genero con un solo input pero como esta en el ciclo while se genera muchas veces pero a la hora de guardar no inserta nada no se si me entiendan 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-condensed" id="exportar">
<thead class="thead-dark text-center">
<tr>
  <th rowspan="2">Partes y Accesorios<br>
    Frente Exterior
  </th>
  <th colspan="4">Estado</th> 
</tr> 

<tr>
<th>Cantidad</th>
<th>Bueno</th>
<th>Malo</th>
<th>No aplica</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die (mysqli_error());
$query="select id_partes,partes from partes_accesorios where partes in('emblemas','defensa delantera','unidades', 'direccionales')";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error($con));

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

$datos=$row[0]."||".
$row[1];
?>
  <tr>  
    <td class="text-center">       
    <input type="hidden" name="nombre" id="nombre" style=" border:0;" value="<?php echo$row[1]?>">  
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
    <input type="text" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" style=" border:0;">  
    </td>   
    <td class="text-center">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox" value="bueno"> Bueno   
    </label>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox" value="malo"> Malo
    </label>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox" value="no_aplica"> Na
    </label>
  </tr>  
<?php
 }
mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ("Problemas al llamar tabla".mysqli_error());
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

tampoco guarda mis checkbox aunque se supone que los estoy utilizando como un array este es mi código para insertar

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die (mysqli_error());

$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];

if($insertar==true){
if($_POST['checkbox'] != "")
{
         if(is_array($_POST['checkbox']))
         {
             // realizamos el ciclo
             while(list($key,$value) = each($_POST['checkbox'])) 
            {
$sql="INSERT INTO checklist_accesorios (nombre,cantidad,estado) VALUES ('$nombre','$cantidad','$value')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ("Problemas al insertar".mysqli_error());
            }
         }
}
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Lo que querés hacer es que cuando se agrega un resultado se haga un request a algún endpoint?

Comment: No estoy tratando de hacer un tipo checklist lo que se ve en la imagen es un pequeño formulario entonces esos datos los quiero almacenar en otra tabla de la bd quiero insertar por ejemplo: unidades-139-bueno, direccionales-16-malo, defensa-1-NA , emblemas-2-bueno y que cada una de las opciones pertenezca a un mismo id o vehículo , pretendo hacer un chequeo de vehiculos para ver si estan en buen estado no se si me entiendas

Comment: y mi problema es que todo lo tengo que manejar creo que con array ya que cada opción de mi tabla que muestro en la imagen vienen de un ciclo while pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: El estado no deberian ser 3 checkbox en diferentes columnas. O usas un combo con opciones, o usas algun tipo de radio button que te permita seleccionar solo una de las opciones. No creo que puedas seleccionar multiples opciones para una misma parte

Comment: si es lo que estaba viendo con el checkbox doy a opción de que se puedan elegir los 3 y con radio button solo 1 que es lo mejor para este caso

Comment: vos queres que seleccione 3 o 1? la respuesta la sabes vos :)

Comment: si solo una opción lo cambiare por radiobuttons

Comment: Tu codigo esta complicado, porque el concepto de la pantalla que estas armando esta erroneo. Yo empezaria por entender que hace la pantalla y como lo tiene que hacer, para luego saber como guardar esa info en la base de datos. Igual, es muy probable que al armar la DB ya te hayas dado cuenta que no podes tener 3 estados para una misma parte ;)

Comment: si esta algo complicado alguna sugerencia de como crear un checklist para poder armar una estructura correcta ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero, en vez de checkbox deberias tener un radio, ya que solo deberias tener una opcion valida, o si vas a manejar cada opcion independiente deberian tener un name distinto las 3 opciones.
segundo, hay 2 maneras de que guardes esa informacion, una es con peticiones ajax, es la mejor practica pero es mas complejo ya que tendrias que usar javascript. yo te recomiendo que metas esa tabla dentro de un form, y pones al final un boton de guardar
ahora cada row  pon por ejemplo

```
    <input type="text" name="item[<?= $row[0] ?>][cantidad]" id="cantidad" style=" border:0;">
 <input type="checkbox" name="item[<?= $row[0] ?>][checkbox]" id="checkbox" value="bueno">
```

de esta manera, recibes en el php un $_POST con un array con los datos, y puedes hacer un foreach o while para guardar cada uno de los datos por ejemplo algo asi

```
foreach($_POST['item'] as $key => $item){
   $resultado = $mysqli->query("UPDATE tabla SET ..etcetera..  where id=".$key);
}
```

no tengo todo tu codigo pero es un ejemplo para dar a enteder la idea.